# What should be the best layout elements for this android screen?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, layout

I want to achieve this layout screen(attached here-in) in android, i tried with designing the page as per below code, but while testing the screen on device it went horribly slow.

On browsing few links, came to know that it has happened due to excessive nesting of linear layouts, same is reflected in hierarchy viewer.

What should be done here to design this app ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/player_reg_back"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="162dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Photo Upload" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewstatus"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Profile Status"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextstatus"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewcity"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="City"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextcity"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:ems="10" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLocation"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:ems="10" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewmobile"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Mobile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMobile"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/skill"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Skill"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerskill"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewfactor"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Expertise"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerfactor"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share the image link in a comment

Comment: share your image link with question

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu - thanks for the reply ....image for the same can be seen at http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79351/what-should-be-the-best-layout-elements-for-this-android-screen

Comment: @AlokNair ....thanks alok...you can see the image at this link...http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79351/what-should-be-the-best-layout-elements-for-this-android-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `TableLayout` inside your root `LinearLayout`, and for each `LinearLayout` you have used here, replace it with a corresponding `TableRow`. You can use this [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_TableLayout_and_TableRow_Tutorial) as reference for this, the sample in link is basically for a form design just like in your case.

Hope this helps :) If you have any issues while implementing, feel free to add comment or update question or post new question for further help.

Comment: @Alok...thanks for the answer....looks good....but there is one photo image  to be uploaded in the top ...what can be the best element to fit that in screen and in which layout.. ?

Comment: I didnt get what your point. Can you please make it more clear?

Comment: there is one imageView element which will be used to upload the photo of user....should we keep that outside tablelayout....as that will have a button also below that to upload the photo...? i hope this makes question clear...

Comment: Put it inside the tablelayout only and if you dont want the button below to come in next row and want it in same row as of that image view, then add a vertical linearlayout and place them both inside this linearlayout.

Comment: @rahulfhp_opensource_geek yw :) post here if you need any help